# How to extract the value of each first item in Pug array

Tags: arrays, pug

I'm trying to get the first item in this array using Pug.

```
- val newx = {'O1_Carmine':'#E54A34', 'O2_Lipstick':'#D04735'}

each val,index in newx
    .span2(style={ background: val, color: 'black', height: '3em'} class='pad1')
        p index[0]
```

This renders

```html
<div class="span2 pad1" style="background:#E54A34;color:black;height:3em;"><p>index[0]</p></div>
<div class="span2 pad1" style="background:#D04735;color:black;height:3em;"><p>index[0]</p></div>
```

but I'm trying to get;

```html
<div class="span2 pad1" style="background:#E54A34;color:black;height:3em;"><p>O1_Carmine</p></div>
<div class="span2 pad1" style="background:#D04735;color:black;height:3em;"><p>O2_Lipstick</p></div>
```

Any tips?

Comment: Note that objects in JavaScript do NOT guarantee order when looped through.  If the order is important to you then you should be using an array instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
each val,index in newx
    .span2(style={ background: val, color: 'black', height: '3em'} class='pad1')
        p= index
```

Note the `=` after the `p`, and no need for `[0]` (and that first line should read `- var`, not `- val`)

Comment: Thanks - yes val was a typo - in the actual code i'm using is '- const '. I was writing  the common form. Your solution works!